# How are these two sentences different?

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence-meaning

Is there any difference between these 2 sentences:

> My parents encouraged me to be a doctor, but I didn't want to.
>
> My parents encouraged me to be a doctor, but I didn't want to be.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct, and is what I would use, but the second just seems awkward and lacks a direct object for the verb `be`. To fix this one would have to say

> My parents encouraged me to be a doctor, but I didn't want to be one.

Where one refers to a doctor.

Comment: OP's second version isn't quite as obviously unacceptable as *My parents encouraged me to have an eye test, but I didn't want to have*, but it's in that general area. Definitely to be avoided.